# grab piece of string with dynamic size

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say that I have string `I,RT______,_,__;` I want to grab integer which will be in addition to the string like `I,RT,______,_,__;09123103912093` so I want to grab only this `09123103912093` value which will be dynamic value, everytime different integer.

Problem is that I dont know fixed size of this integer, it could be `12` or just `2` or could be `09123103912093`.

p.s. if it's worth mention, after this integer is end of file. No further content.

Comment: Is this part of your string fixed: `I,RT______,_,__;` ?

Comment: content of that string part is not fixed, but string length is.

Comment: This would be a perfect application for a regular expression. I'm not too sharp with them, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file to the end with: `TextReader.ReadToEnd();` and you get your string.
Now split the string. The seperator char is `;` and you get a `string[]`:

```
  string[] myStringArr = myString.Split(';');
```

Now take the second item of the array: `myStringArr[1]`.

Then you could parse the string to int:

`int myValue = Int32.Parse(myStringArr[1]);`

---

Another possibility would be the usage of `string.Substring(x,y);`:

To use it, you have to find the startindex of the string (in your case, the index of the semicolon plus one char): `myString.IndexOf(';') +1`.
Then you need the length of the the substring.
 
Since your string ends after the needed int value, you can simply use the whole length of the string and substract the index of the semicolon: `myString.Length - (myString.IndexOf(';') +1)` 
So your code should be: 
`myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(';')+1,myString.Length - (myString.IndexOf(';') +1));`
MSDN-Article: [String.Substring Method (Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hxthx5h6.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

```
string tmp = "I,RT,______,_,__;09123103912093"
int yourInt = int.Parse(tmp.Split(';').Last());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use some simple string manipulation functions to achieve this:

```
int indexOfSemiColon = myString.LastIndexOf(":");
string numberString = myString.SubString(indexOfSemiColon + 1);

int resultingInteger = int.Parse(numberString);
```